# How to configure JUnit test suite?

Tags: java, junit, hudson, automated-tests, sonarqube

I have a Java project which has layered structure. And each time when commit is made [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) build is running with all test cases to make sure that code is not broken by new changes. But this may take considerable amount of time due to running test cases for persistence (Hibernate) layer. Also there is a [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) build which runs each night.

Now I am looking for a way of optimizing test running. I want to remove persistence layers tests from Hudson build and only run it in Sonar. Now it should have two different test suites (profiles).

Any suggestion very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking to use JUnit Categories - https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0

You can then configure your build server to run specific categories at different times

More info here - https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already found this resource. The thing is when we define a category and exclude that will exclude from both `Hudson` and `Sonar`

Comment: Instead of having an "exclude" category, have two categories. A "hudson" category and a "Sonar" category, hudson will only run the hudson categories and sonar will only run the sonar categories. (Ovbiously use better category names). If a test needs to be run for both hudson and sonar, then you can assign it both categories

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Junit 4.8 or higher you can use JUnit `Categories` to separate your tests and run only tests that are in certain categories.

For more information see:

- Wiki page on GitHub repository of junit-team: [junit4, Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories)
- Tutorial on DZone: [A Closer Look at JUnit Categories](http://java.dzone.com/articles/closer-look-junit-categories)
- Guide on Maven Surefire Plugin: [Using JUnit Categories](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#using-junit-categories)

Comment: First link to Categories is broken, may replace with https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to separate into 2 test phases:

- unit, for the fast-running tests
- integration, for the Hibernate-style slower ones.

Unit tests are run by Surefire plugin, with integration ones run by [Failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/)

These run in a different phases of the maven standard build lifecycle, so you can set the integration tests to only run on your SONAR build.